# WPF, How to bind a TextBox.Text property to a property of a data object and another Textbox.Text

Tags: wpf, binding

I have two WPF `Textbox`, `Textbox1` and `Textbox2`. `Texbox2` changes when the user types anything in `Textbox1` and also `Textbox2.Text` needs to be loaded/saved to data source. I can either bind the `Textbox2.Text` to the `Textbox1.Text` like

```
<TextBox Name="Textbox2" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Textbox1}"/>
```

or to data source

```
<TextBox Name="Textbox2" Text="{Binding Path="AProperty"}"/>
```

How can I have both?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `Binding`s without prior knowledge of MVVM.
`TextBox1.Text` can be bound to say `TextProperty1` and `TextBox2.Text` can be bound to `TextProperty1` in the *ViewModel* (the class which is assigned as `DataContext`).

**The ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    string _TextProperty1;
    public string TextProperty1
    {
        get { return _TextProperty1; }
        set
        {
            if (_TextProperty1 != value)
            {
                _TextProperty1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextProperty1");
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextProperty2");
            }
        }
    }

    string _TextProperty2;
    public string TextProperty2
    {
        get { return _TextProperty2; }
        set
        {
            if (_TextProperty2 != value)
            {
                _TextProperty2 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextProperty2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see you will be notifying both the properties while setting `TextProperty1`.